# Auto hide <ul> listing on load using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

How can I automatically show this listing collapsed *without modifying* the HTML structure? This means I want to collapse all the folders of the tree.

And initially, instead of showing this:

[image]

I want to this:

[image]

This is my try with no luck:

```js
$('#master-ul').hide()

$('#master-ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  return false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
<ul id="master-ul">
  <li class="folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> first_folder
    <ul>
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> jose.dat</li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder
        <ul>
          <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> as.dat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> third_folder
        <ul>
          <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> a.dat</li>
          <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> b.dat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**PS:** There can be more than one root folder. This means that having more than one `first_folder` in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use css then use jq for change that?

```js
$('#master-ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#secondlvl').slideToggle();
  return false
});
$('.folder').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  return false
});
```

```css
#master-ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />


<ul id="master-ul">
  <li class="folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> first_folder
    <ul id='secondlvl'>
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> jose.dat</li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder
        <ul>
          <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> as.dat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> third_folder
            <ul id="thirdlvl">
               <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> a.dat</li>
               <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> b.dat</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:**
Add `#secondlvl` for control the first `slideToggle()`
**Additional:**
If you don't want `secondlvl` id you can use `$('#master-ul > li > ul').slideToggle();` instead of `$('#secondlvl').slideToggle();` for slide the first `ul`.

```js
$('#master-ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#master-ul > li > ul').slideToggle();
  return false
});
$('.folder').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
  return false
});
```

```css
#master-ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />


<ul id="master-ul">
  <li class="folder">
    <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> first_folder
    <ul>
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> jose.dat</li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder
        <ul>
          <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> as.dat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="folder">
        <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> third_folder
            <ul id="thirdlvl">
               <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> a.dat</li>
               <li class="file "><i class="fa fa-file "></i> b.dat</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have added the missing JS 

Comment: Oh, I missed on the post that I need to collpase all the inner `<li>` items too

Comment: Thanks Alessio, i didn't add it because i don't know if avion already has its own code

Comment: You have modified the HTML by adding an `id` tag. As stated on the post, I can't do it as this is a dinamically generated HTML content from an input array using Javascript :(

Comment: See Additional in my post ;)

Comment: @Avión have you tested?

Comment: No! I'm out of the office some days. I will let you know when I test it!